# Writing an awk script that reads variable from command line

Tags: awk

I am trying to write an `awk` script that can read a users input from command line and store it as a variable.

I know that if I compile from command line and do

```
./myawk.awk -v ID=4 text.sql
```

ID will be a variable set to 4. However, the input test cases I am given for my script are just

```
./myawk.awk ID=4 text.sql
```

The final goal of the script is to take an ID, find any line that begins with

```
-- ID
```

and print the following line. What I have so far is

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
  if ($1 ~/--/ && $2 ~/^ID/){
    x = NR+1
  }
  while (NR <= x){
    print $0
  }
}
```

How  would I able to read the variable ID without altering the line and adding `-v` before it, as well maybe give me advice on my current `awk` script.

Answer (score 3):

If a variable assignment is given as a file operand on the command line of an `awk` script, that assignment will be carried out when `awk` gets to that point in using the file operands.

Example:

```
awk -f script.awk a=1 file1 file2 a=2 file3 a=3 file4
```

Here, the `awk` variable `a` will be set to `1` before reading `file1`.  The variable will retain that value (unless it's changed by the `awk` program) until the file `file2` has been read. It is then set to `2` etc.

This means that your command line properly sets the variable `ID` to `4` before reading `text.sql`.

The difference between `-v ID=4` and this is that `ID` will not have been set in any `BEGIN` block.  Using `-v ID=4` sets `ID` to `4` and it *will* be available in `BEGIN` blocks.

Another issue with your code is that you use `ID` as a literal *string* in

```
if ($1 ~/--/ && $2 ~/^ID/){
```

That is, you test whether the second field starts with the string `ID`.

It also seems as if you expect your `while` loop to loop over the lines of the file.   That line-by-line reading loop is already built into the way `awk` operates already and it *very seldom* needs to be explicit.

Instead,

```
$1 == "--" && $2 == ID { getline; print }
```

This will use string comparisons (not regular expression matches) to check whether the first whitespace-delimited field on the current line is the string `--` and whether the second such field is the value of the variable `ID`.  If so, the next line of input is read and printed.

To use regular expressions instead,

```
$0 ~ "^-- " ID "$" { getline; print }
```

This would match every line that starts with a double dash and a single space, followed by the value of `ID` and the end of the line (`$` matches the end of the line).  The line after the matching line would be printed.

Comment: This is the best answer — but why are you using ``getline``?

Comment: @G-Man They want to match the ID, then print the next line.

Comment: Dang; I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to read user input with awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        printf "Enter an ID: "
        # "-" is the filename for stdin
        getline id < "-"
    }
    # then we can use that value however we like
    $1 == "--" && $2 == id {getline; print}
' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I Tried with below method and it worked fine


 #!/bin/bash
echo "enter the number"
read p
awk -v p="$p" '$1 == "--" && $2 == p {print $0}' filename
```

Comment: n@praveen:~$ sh l.sh 
enter the number
4
--4praveenajay10

Comment: As tested it looks for value of p

Comment: @Kusalananda I edited the code kindly check now